# Get total number of records for groups of data in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using a SQL Server 2008R2 database. I have a query that I use to get some lab-result data from our database for patients who have had more than 2 visits to our office. Here is the query:

```
;WITH PatientData (patient_id,last_name, first_name, ethnic_group,
race, icdcode, encounter_date, test_performed, result_value,
result_units )
AS
(
SELECT pat.patient_id, pat.last_name, Pat.first_name, pat.ethnic_group,
pat.race, pl.icdcode, enc.encounter_date, lab.test_performed, lab.result_value,
lab.result_units
FROM dbo.dem_patient pat
RIGHT JOIN dbo.med_problemlist as pl
ON pat.patient_id = pl.patient_id
JOIN dbo.enc_encounter as enc
ON pat.patient_id = enc.patient_id
JOIN dbo.med_labresult as lab
ON pat.patient_id = lab.patient_id
WHERE pl.icdcode like '250%' AND
enc.encounter_date >= '01/01/2012' AND enc.encounter_date <= '12/31/2012' AND
pat.last_name != 'test' AND (lab.test_performed = 'HgbA1c' OR 
lab.test_performed = 'Hemoglobin A1c')
GROUP BY pat.patient_id, pat.last_name, Pat.first_name, pat.ethnic_group,
pat.race, pl.icdcode, enc.encounter_date, lab.test_performed, lab.result_value,
lab.result_units
)
SELECT patient_id,last_name, first_name, ethnic_group,
race, icdcode, encounter_date, test_performed, result_value,
result_units
FROM PatientData pd1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT patient_id 
                FROM PatientData pd2 
                WHERE pd2.patient_id  = pd1.patient_id  
                GROUP BY patient_id 
                HAVING COUNT(*)>1 )
ORDER BY pd1.race, pd1.ethnic_group
```

This works fine for getting a list of patients and their lab result values. It returns something like this:

```
patient_id    encounter_date    test_performed    result_value    result_units
00001         01/15/2012        HgbA1c            5.6             %
00001         05/03/2012        HgbA1c            8.6             %
00025         02/02/2012        HgbA1c            9.1             %
00064         07/01/2012        HgbA1c            7.6             %
```

However, I'd now like to group this data, and get a total number of results between different values of results. For example, I'd like to have results that look something like this:

```
LessThan7%    7%To8%     8%To9%    GreaterThan9%
775           289        365       154
```

I've been able to do something similar in the past utilizing the CROSS JOIN function. However, never with a query this complicated. I could really use some help.

Thank you!

UPDATE:

On the advice below, I've updated the query to the following:

```
;WITH PatientData (patient_id,last_name, first_name, ethnic_group,
race, icdcode, encounter_date, test_performed, result_value,
result_units )
AS
(
SELECT pat.patient_id, pat.last_name, Pat.first_name, pat.ethnic_group,
pat.race, pl.icdcode, enc.encounter_date, lab.test_performed, lab.result_value,
lab.result_units
FROM dbo.dem_patient pat
RIGHT JOIN dbo.med_problemlist as pl
ON pat.patient_id = pl.patient_id
JOIN dbo.enc_encounter as enc
ON pat.patient_id = enc.patient_id
JOIN dbo.med_labresult as lab
ON pat.patient_id = lab.patient_id
WHERE pl.icdcode like '250%' AND
enc.encounter_date >= '01/01/2012' AND enc.encounter_date <= '12/31/2012' AND
pat.last_name != 'test' AND (lab.test_performed = 'HgbA1c' OR 
lab.test_performed = 'Hemoglobin A1c')
GROUP BY pat.patient_id, pat.last_name, Pat.first_name, pat.ethnic_group,
pat.race, pl.icdcode, enc.encounter_date, lab.test_performed, lab.result_value,
lab.result_units
)
select sum(case when isnumeric(result_value) = 1
       then (case when result_value < 7.0 then 1 else 0 end) 
       end) as [LessThan7%],
       sum(case when isnumeric(result_value) = 1
       then (case when result_value >= 7.0 and result_value < 8.0 then 1 else 0 end) 
       end) as [7%to8%],
       sum(case when isnumeric(result_value) = 1
       then (case when result_value >= 8.0 and result_value < 9.0 then 1 else 0 end) 
       end) as [8%to9%],
       sum(case when isnumeric(result_value) = 1
       then (case when result_value >= 9.0 then 1 else 0 end)
       end) as [GreaterThan9%]
FROM PatientData pd1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT patient_id 
                FROM PatientData pd2 
                WHERE pd2.patient_id  = pd1.patient_id  
                GROUP BY patient_id 
                HAVING COUNT(*)>1 )
```

However, I'm still getting the "Arithmic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric"

Any additional help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a conditional aggregation:

```
with query as (your query here)
select sum(case when result_value < 0.07 then 1 else 0 end) as [LessThan7%],
       sum(case when result_value >= 0.07 and result_value < 0.08 then 1 else 0 end) as [7%to8%],
       sum(case when result_value >= 0.08 and result_value < 0.09 then 1 else 0 end) as [8%to9%],
       sum(case when result_value >= 0.09 then 1 else 0 end) as [GreaterThan9%]
from query
```

Arrange your query to go in the `with` clause.

If result_value is stored as a character, then try this:

```
select sum(case when isnumeric(result_value) = 1
                then (case when result_value < 0.07 then 1 else 0 end)
            end) as [LessThan7%],
       sum(case when isnumeric(result_value) = 1
                then result_value >= 0.07 and result_value < 0.08 then 1 else 0 end)
           end) as [7%to8%],
       sum(case when isnumeric(result_value) = 1
                then (case when result_value >= 0.08 and result_value < 0.09 then 1 else 0 end)
            end) as [8%to9%],
       sum(case when isnumeric(result_value) = 1
                then (case when result_value >= 0.09 then 1 else 0 end)
           end) as [GreaterThan9%]
```

You need the nested `case` statements to ensure that `isnumeric()` runs *before* the attempted conversion.

Comment: This query makes sense to me, and seems like it should work, but I'm getting an error that says "conversion failed when converting varchar value '6.6' to data type int"

Comment: @MLorenzen . . . I suspect this is occurring somewhere else in the query.  Somewhere, there is an implicit conversion from 6.6 to an integer.  This could be happening if your conditions are `result_value < 7` and `result_value` is a varchar.  In this case, either do an explicit conversion (`cast(result_value as float) < 7`) or change the constant to 7.0.

Comment: thanks for the follow-up. I've added the .0 to the query, but am now getting a different error. I've added the updated query above..

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but I'm still getting the same error. I've updated what I'm running above.

Comment: @MLorenzen . . . What column in the query is being stored as a character?  I assumed it was `result_value`.